# Shopping cart using $_SESSION and array_push doesn't seem to remember cart items

Tags: php, arrays, session, push, cart

The session storage array seem to only remember one key value pair. When I push the back button in the browser the array seems empty. What am I doing wrong?
Here's the code:
thanks for your help

```html
<?php
if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) {
    session_start();
       $_SESSION['cart']=array();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Shoppy</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><a href="index.php">back to store</a></div>

   <?php include 'products.inc.php'; ?>
   <?php $p=$_GET["product"] ?>
   <span><?php echo $products[$p]['name']; ?> </span><?php echo $products[$p]['price']; ?> €
   <div>
    <img src="<?php echo $products[$p]['picture']; ?>" alt="">
   </div>
   
 
 
 <form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="form" value=<?php echo $p ?>>
  <button type="submit">buy</button>
 </form>
 <?php if (!empty ($_POST) && isset($_POST))
{
 array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_POST['form']);
 

 } ?>
 <?php include 'cart.inc.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe because you clear the cart on every page load? (line 4)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) {
    session_start();
       $_SESSION['cart']=array();
}
```

to

```
session_start();
if( !isset($_SESSION['cart']) ) {
       $_SESSION['cart']=array();
}
```

You need to call `session_start()` before attempting to do anything with the session.  Also when you check for whether or not it is set, check a session variable (i.e. `isset($_SESSION['someindex'])`, not session itself (i.e. `isset($_SESSION)`).

Comment: Yeah this seems to be working mostly but my cart doesn't update unless I push on buy. This is my cart:

Comment: <code> <?php if (!empty ($_POST) && isset($_POST))
{?> <div>Your shopping cart contains:</div>

<?php 
 
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $p) { ?>
  <ul>
  <li>
   <span><?php echo $products[$p]['name']; ?> </span><?php echo $products[$p]['price']; ?> €</span>
      
  </li>
 </ul>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php } else 
 {?><div>Your shopping cart is empty</div>

 <?php }?></code>

Comment: @BartMertens Its normal for Back button to return a cached page (i.e. old data). After going back, click `refresh`.